# HTML onkeyup Event Attribute to Run PHP Function

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible for the HTML onkeyup event attribute to run a PHP function instead of a Javascript function?

If not, then is it possible to immediately have the javascript function call the PHP function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda... You can have an onkeyup event make an ajax call that would run a php script and return a value/object/etc.

If you are using jQuery, you can look at the [documentation to make the call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

A sample code will be:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function () {
  $.ajax('http://www.domain.com/file.php')
      .done(function(data) {
         // javascript to run on success
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## No

The **client** can trigger an `event` to trigger a call to the **server** where **PHP** is executed.

I'll explain with a graph so you can see it more clearly

```
[Client] (browser with javascript) does something
 -> event is triggered
    -> ajax request is sent to server

[Server] (that runs php scripts) receives request
 -> looks for the script to run
    -> if found, runs script
       -> output is returned to client

[Client] receives response
 -> client does something with response
```

As you can see, these technologies reside in completely different environments, hosted behind lots of protocols that help with transparent communication

## The call to php functions may be emulated

please read on the following subjects

- URL Rewriting (you can make calls `like http://host/phpfunc/param1/param2/paramN`)
- javascript (what it does and what it doesn't do)
- ajax (asynchronous calls to the server)
- jquery (a nice library to help out)